# tcp http webserver keeps stalling

Tags: vb.net, tcp, httpserver

I have been trying to figure out the code at the following link. [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/0400__Socket-Network/TcpListenerbasedWebserver.htm) and it kind of works except for one thing, The problem with the code is that the index.html wont show untill I actually stop debugging in visual studio. It looks like the clientSocket.Close() in sendHTMLResponse is not closing?

Could sombody help figure out why the code is stalling?